# NFC reading not working with the usage of IPC

Tags: android, binding, ipc, nfc

I have made app which uses NFC and reads IsoDep types of tags. Everything works just fine and I can read NFC tags normally, repetitively. I am trying to pass the information from the NFC tag to a remote service.

But after binding to a service for interprocess communication (IPC), NFC is not working anymore properly:

bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

In onServiceConnected I establish connection via AIDL IPC mechanism with service of another app and then It gets very weird. I can scan NFC tag only once or twice and then NFC stops working at all. onNewIntent method is not called anymore.

I tried press home button, the activity goes to the background and when I try to read NFC tag from there, It does not even show the dialog which offers various apps with NFC support. It starts working again only when I restart the NFC in Settings.

I am using Galaxy S5 with Android Marshmallow. NFC works normally in other apps (I guess those are not using IPC). I am also using foreground dispatching as described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch

I have searched everywhere and I am run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it does work with IsoDep NFC tags of particular type (tags inside of ID Card in this case), which I have to use. I have used a wrong types of NFC tags so far. I guess the problem is due to the Service I am binding. It is service from a 3rd party app so I cannot change it.